# Are reflexive relations transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let  $R=\{(2,2),(3,3)\}$.  Then $S=R \circ R= \{(2,2),(3,3)\}$

So, $S \subset R$, there is theory that $R$ is transitive. Then every reflexive relation is transitive?

Comment: The point here is that "reflexive" only talks about a couple of the possible relations; "transitive" is a strict requirement on nearly all the relations. It's much harder to be transitive than reflexive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $R=\bigl\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3)\bigr\}$. Then $R\circ R=R\cup\bigl\{(1,3)\bigr\}$ and therefore $R\circ R\not\subset R$.

Comment: Should $R\circ R$ be a _true_ subset of $R$, or does the relation $\subseteq$ suffice?

Comment: It will suffice $\subseteq$.